# Correctly importing components in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, import

Currently I am exporting a component

```
  export default function ChooseNamespace() {


  return (
    <View>
      <Text>HELLO</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

And importing it here:

```
import ChooseNamespace from "./screens/ChooseNamespace";

   const AppDrawerNavigator = () => {
    console.log(storeState.userNamespace);
    if (storeState.userNamespace === null) {
      return <ChooseNamespace />;
    } else {
      return (
        <AppDrawer.Navigator
          drawerContent={(props) => <AppDrawerContent {...props} />}
          drawerContentOptions={{
            activeTintColor: "blue",
            labelStyle: {
              color: "white",
            },
          }}
        >
          <AppDrawer.Screen
            name="Chat"
            children={(props) => <ChatScreen name="Blindly Chat" {...props} />}
          />
          <AppDrawer.Screen
            name="Profile"
            children={(props) => <ProfileScreen name="Profile" {...props} />}
          />
          <AppDrawer.Screen
            name="DirectMessages"
            children={(props) => <DMScreen {...props} />}
          />
          <AppDrawer.Screen
            name="Threads"
            children={(props) => <ThreadsScreen {...props} />}
          />
          <AppDrawer.Screen
            name="Settings"
            children={(props) => <SettingsScreen {...props} />}
          />
          <AppDrawer.Screen
            name="Support"
            children={(props) => <SupportScreen {...props} />}
          />
        </AppDrawer.Navigator>
      );
    }
  };
```

Which is then throwing the error

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `ChooseNamespace`.

Can someone try an explain the issue here? I am having a bit of trouble finding it.

Comment: can you post the code for ```AppDrawerNavigator```

Comment: @KetanRamteke It is up

Comment: Are you sure you only exporting this function?

Comment: @KetanRamteke Yes the pasted code is what is there. The export default function() and import ChooseNamespace is all there.

Comment: in given code there is no ```export default AppDrawerNavigator```

Comment: Even I I try and render the component outside of the navigator, it throws the same error. I imported the component straight into index.js and it throws the same error.

Comment: Can u try my code

Answer (score 0):

```
const ChooseNamespace =()=> {


  return (
    <View>
      <Text>HELLO</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
export default ChooseNamespace
```

Try this code. ES6 doesn't allow `export default` const. You must declare the constant first then export it. Or if WANT to have a function then do this:

```
function ChooseNamespace() {


  return (
    <View>
      <Text>HELLO</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default ChooseNamespace;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
  return (
           <>
             {
              storeState.userNamespace === null? 
               <ChooseNamespace/>:
               <YourDrawerView/>
                        
            }
         </>  
    
       );
```